# Individual detail buttons and global detail button

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, events

i'm trying to hide and show details in an infographic by clicking on a button directly in the info-graphic. Theres 3 buttons that i want to individualy show there content. But at the same time i have another detail button that should show and hide all of the details.

Here's my code so far.

```
<div class="item" style="background: #eeeeef;">
    <div class="it-con alltag-con">
        <div class="einlagen-con-neu">
            <div class="ein-con-rel">
                <img class="einlage-neu" src="<?php bloginfo('stylesheet_directory'); ?>/img/einlagen-ip/alltag-ip-min.png" />
                <div class="detail-1-alltag detail-inf">
                    <div class="detail-inf-con hide-ein">
                        <h5>Pelotte</h5>
                        <span class="line-karo"></span>
                        <p>stimuliert die Muskulatur
                            <br> und entlastet gleichzeitig
                            <br> die Achillessehne</p>
                        <span class="caro-einlage"></span>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="detail-2-alltag detail-inf">
                    <div class="detail-inf-con hide-ein">
                        <h5>Detorsionskern</h5>
                        <span class="line-karo"></span>
                        <p>stärkt den Mittelfußbereich
                            <br> und bietet statische
                            <br> Korrektur
                        </p>
                        <span class="caro-einlage"></span>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="detail-3-alltag detail-inf">
                    <div class="detail-inf-con hide-ein">
                        <h5>Fersenschale</h5>
                        <span class="line-karo"></span>
                        <p>umfasst die Ferse sanft
                            <br> und führt den Fuß optimal
                        </p>
                        <span class="caro-einlage"></span>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="mess-text">
            <span class="x-btn">&#10005;<br></span>
            <span class="ei-btn"><span class="karo"></span>INFO
            </span>
            <h4><?php the_field('ueberschrift_einlagen', 102); ?></h4>
            <br>
            <p>
                <?php the_field( 'texte_einlagen', 102); ?>
            </p>
            <span class="ei-btn-s"><span class="karo"></span> INFOS</span>
        </div>
        <div class="toggle">
            <div class="det-btn"><span class="karo"></span> Detail</div>
            <div class="inf-btn">Info</div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

my jquery

```
$(".caro-einlage").click(function(e) {
    //e.preventDefault();
    $(this).parent(".detail-inf-con").toggleClass("hide-ein");
    //$(this).prev(".state-1").toggleClass("hide");
});

$(".alltag-con .det-btn").click(function(e) {
    //e.preventDefault();
    $(".alltag-con .detail-inf-con").toggleClass("hide-ein");
    //$(this).prev(".state-1").toggleClass("hide");
});
```

Here's also a jsfiddler. https://jsfiddle.net/JayKray/sxk5e5a4/1/

Help is really apreciated.

: )

Comment: Please create jsfiddle of the same

Comment: please create jsfiddle or plunker

Comment: Created a jsfiddle. The js code is mostly there to explain what i wanna do. Thanks for looking into this. : ) https://jsfiddle.net/JayKray/sxk5e5a4/1/